# object doesn't support this property or method in vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub main()

Dim i, j As Integer

Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
Worksheets("sheet2").Activate

For i = 1 To 200
    For j = 1 To 200
        If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(j, 1) Then
            Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 1).inerior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

I don't know why does it return error? it seems that everything is right. but it says that object doesn't support this property or method.
I have tried excel 2013.

Comment: you have a **Typo** , it should be `Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed` , and NOT `inerior`

Comment: Besides that, you need to define `Dim i As integer, j As Integer`, otherwise`i` will be defined `As Variant`. Also, it's better to stay away from `Activate`.

Comment: lowercase letter after a dot is usually a sign that `.inerior` doesn't exist. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399691/excel-vba-highlight-duplicates-in-active-column

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through your code quickly to remove this error *and avoid future errors*. Most of this is covered in Shai Rado's comments.

---

```
Dim i, j As Integer
```

This is declaring `i` as a variant. You need to be specific like this:

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
```

---

The following code is doing nothing and can be removed. You would only need to `Activate` a worksheet if you wanted to use the `ActiveSheet` object. This is highly discouraged -- so well done for not doing that.

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
```

The exception being if you want Excel to activate a different sheet to the one from which you called the sub at once the macro has run, then you could put one of these `.Activate` statements at the end of your sub

---

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 1).inerior.Color = vbRed
```

There is a typo here. `Interior` rather than  `inerior`. You can usually spot these errors because you can see that your property hasn't been capitalised as you would expect.

---

You haven't specified which `Workbook` these sheets are in. As `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` are default names, you are particularly at risk if you have two or more workbooks open when running your sub. Excel can become confused and run the code on the wrong workbook. Here are a few ways to avoid this:

1. Change `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells()` to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells()`
2. Use the sheet object names. These are simply `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` etc if you haven't changed them. E.g. `Sheet1.Cells()`

---

So here is your final code

```
Sub main()

Dim i as Integer, j As Integer

For i = 1 To 200
    For j = 1 To 200
        If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet2.Cells(j, 1) Then
            Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'Sheet2.Activate
End Sub
```

I would also advise that you name your sub to something that better describes *what it does*, rather than `main`.